# Not able to set value for Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect in ExtJs 3.4

Tags: extjs3

I am using ExtJs 3.4.

When i set value to Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect, I am getting this error.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearSelections' of undefined in MultiSelect.js:245".

If I have to clear the selected values in "Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect" before setting the selected values, then how can i do that.

Please give suggestions for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this component](http://trac.geoext.org/browser/ext/3.4.0/examples/ux/MultiSelect.js), then in `setValue` method there is call to `this.view.clearSelections()`, and that probably causes issues. `view` is created in `onRender` method. So your combo is probably not rendered when you call `setValue`.

I see 3 solutions:

1. Ensure combo is rendered when you call `setValue`
2. Check is combo is rendered; call `setValue` when it is, assign `value` when it isn't
3. Override `MultiSelect` and fix it